# how to make the div fits all of it's width?

Tags: css, html

i have a html div that is styled with css, this div contains some data(a string), and although setting the div width the same as the width of another div (25%) but the div only wraps the text that is written inside it while the other div fits the specified area perfectly.

[image]

the div with the problem :

```
 .item_name {
    background-color: #F30;
    position: absolute;
    height: 15%px;
    width: 25%px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

the other div:

```
 .item_block {
    background-origin:content-box;
    background-color:#FFECC1;
    height: 20%;
    width: 25%;
    line-height: 450px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-indent: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;

}
```

here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/encz4/2/) contains my code

Comment: Its occurring because the position is set to absolute.  Going only off of the visual, I don't think this is necessary, however without the HTML its hard to say.  I am guessing you have two divs wrapped by another div.

Comment: Could you also provide the HTML and a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your .item_name as well.  Your height is listed as 15%px and it should be 15% (I'm guessing).  You also have the same problem for your width.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Jsfiddle added

Comment: @Mr.Goose Jsfiddle added

Comment: @KevinBowersox Jsfiddle added

Comment: @MRefaat The fiddle doesn't match the image.

Comment: where is `.item_name` in your fiddle????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has got to be the problem :

```
 height: 15%px;
 width: 25%px;
```

in class `.item_name`
Change it to

```
 height: 15%;
 width: 25%;
```

and add this to you css :

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

this should do pretty much as the parent element has dimension set, child will inherit it in `%age`!!